# Meteor and GroundDB: find by id not returning any entries

Tags: mongodb, meteor, offline-caching, findby, grounddb

I am trying to implement an offline DB for my meteor app and chose to use **“GroundDB”**. Now I am still in my early learning phases but I am having a problem for which I cannot find a solution:

when using .find on my offline-collections, **I cannot find by id**. Every other property works. A typical object from my mongo DB will look like this:

`{_id:"…someid", name:“test”, description:“test”, systemId:"…someID"};`

I can find by name, description and even systemID, but finding by _id is always giving back 0 results.

What could cause this behaviour?

This is only for GroundDB. Finding by _id in mongo database works. Also, the “_id” field in GroundDB is there! When doing a `.find({})` without filters, I can see that all properties, including the _id-field, get copied to groundb.

### Edit

My current code regarding groundDB looks as follows:

```
ExampleCol = new Mongo.Collection('exampleCol');


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('exampleCol', functionexampleColPublication() {
    return ExampleCol.find();
  });
}
```

On Client:

```
ExampleCol_GROUND = new Ground.Collection('exampleCol'
  });
ExampleCol_GROUND.observeSource(ExampleCol.find());
```

And then: 
 `ExampleCol_GROUND.find()` returns all entries, that are also in  ExampleCol. I just cannot `ExampleCol_GROUND.find({_id:"..."})` (0 results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, not sure if it is the most elegant. GroundDB seems to be actively looking for an _id field and trying to use that as a selector. I am not sure what is not working exactly, i guess it has something to do with my _id-field being a string.

Following works though:

instead of a simple `ExampleCol_GROUND.find({_id:"..."})`

i use a 'where' statement now:

```
ExampleCol_GROUND.find({$where: function() {
                   return this._id ==  "..someId.."
                }});
```